# How to remove single quote of a string in a list

Tags: python

When String variable is included in list, it is having the single quote. I do not require that.

Tried to convert datatype. But, getting error while converting.

```
Table = 'temp'
ID = """(SELECT Contents FROM %s)""" % (Table)

list = [ID, 'test', 'new']

print(list)
```

Expected Result:

```
[(SELECT Contents FROM temp), 'test', 'new']
```

Actual Result:

```
['(SELECT Contents FROM temp)', 'test', 'new']
```

Comment: When you print the list object, it adds quotes around any string type items. If you loop over the list and print them, the quotes will not be added.

Comment: A string is always enclosed in quotes, and you see it when you print it, not sure what is the problem here

Comment: I need the expected output to be passed to another method which will fail if it executes the first element which is actually a sql query which will be like below
('(SELECT Contents FROM temp)', 'test', 'new')

Comment: Is there a way to get the expected result?

Comment: Did you actually check this behaviour by passing what you have to the method, it will also help if you post that method here

Comment: I have added a way to get the expected result, but @DeveshKumarSingh is right that your method behavior seems off. Please post the method and we can see if there might be something wrong there. SQL queries are usually passed as strings, and shouldn't need such an operation.

Answer (score 0):

When you directly print a list, it encloses string types in quotes, and the entire list in `[ ]`. So you will have to manually construct a string for your specific output. Also, please avoid naming variables with the name of their class (`list`).

```
op = '[' + list[0] + ', ' + str(list[1:])[1:-1] + ']'
print(op)
# [(SELECT Contents FROM temp), 'test', 'new']
```

To explain, taking the first item directly as a string means it will not have quotes. For the rest, I cast the slice of the list into a string (thus the items will have quotes), and then used `[1:-1]` to remove the first and last characters which were the enclosing `[ ]`.

Comment: But this is giving me output datatype as a String. But, I need the output data type as list or tuple

Comment: Your question was printing list and you gave an expected result. I assumed it was the display output. If you need to pass a list data type, what is your question about? You can't have string types without quotes. Are having an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) while phrasing your question?

Comment: I need to frame query like below

Insert into Table(col1, col3, col3, col4)
Values
((SELECT count(*) FROM `tablename`), '201901', 'test', 133),
((SELECT count(*) + 1 FROM `tablename`), '201901', 'test', 133),
((SELECT count(*) + 2 FROM `tablename`), '201901', 'test', 133)

Comment: As the output is string, it gives like below

Insert into Table(col1, col3, col3, col4)
Values
"((SELECT count(*) FROM `tablename`), '201901', 'test', 133)",
"((SELECT count(*) + 1 FROM `tablename`), '201901', 'test', 133)",
"((SELECT count(*) + 2 FROM `tablename`), '201901', 'test', 133)"

Comment: Please update your question with this. Also include how you are using this query. The `query` will finally be a string before getting passed to some database library right?